# How to disable button with Swift 5.1 in Xcode 12.4 without the sender variable?

Tags: swift, xcode

I am trying to disable a button using Swift in Xcode. I know how to disable a button with the sender variable, but I have not found a way to disable a button without the sender variable. I can't use the sender variable because I have no proof that the user will actually click the button.

I have tried connecting my UIButton to my code using an IBOutlet:

```
@IBOutlet weak var button: UIButton!
```

And then accessing it's properties like so:

```
button.enabled = false
```

I have also tried

```
button.userInteractionEnabled = false
```

Comment: What is wrong with the code you've posted? It would be slightly safer if you added optional chaining, e.g. `button?.isEnabled = false`.

Comment: And what do you mean by "...the sender variable?" Are you talking about referencing a button in it's IBAction method, when you have a parameter `sender` that you can use to refer to the button?

Comment: Do `button.isEnabled = false` not `button.enabled = false`

Comment: I am talking about referencing a button outside it's IBAction method

Comment: @Marco.py yes, that's what `IBOutlet` is for. You can have both an IBOutlet and IBAction at the same time - it's not one or the other.

Comment: I tried `button.isEnabled = false` but it still allows me to press the button

Comment: Make sure you connected the outlet. Go back to the storyboard, and check the outlets panel inside the attributes inspector (press the rightmost icon).

Comment: @aheze You are right, I was not connecting it. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @aheze, you should post the "connect your IBOutlet" comment as an answer so the OP can accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure that your outlet is connected. You can check by going to the storyboard, then opening the outlet connections panel.

[image: 1. Go to "connections inspector" by clicking the rightmost icon at the top of the attributes inspector, which is the right panel. 2. Make sure the outlet is connected, under "Referencing Outlets".]

Result:

[image: Button is grayed out when running the app]

As a side note, you should be doing `button.isEnabled = false`, not `button.enabled = false`.